# TGT session key for windows server 2012/ windows 8

Tags: java, windows, kerberos, jaas

I read many solutions specifying to create allowtgtsessionkey registry key so as to allow TGT session key to be store in LSA cache. May I ask if I am using windows 2012 R2 or Windows 8, do i still need to create this registry key? Using java 7

Update:

I have tried the allowtgtsessionkey registry key but when i get the credentials from LSA cache and write it out to a file  and then compare it with the one that kinit.exe (java) created, there still seem to be some essential information missing.

Output from krb5cc_myuser:

```
# strings krb5cc_myuser
SOME.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN
myuser
SOME.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN
myuser
SOME.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN
krbtgt
SOME.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN
SOME.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN
krbtgt
SOME.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN
:C:]|
"D+"
a(>&;
4   &dx
^ vp
okhd
bSxs
```

Output of strings from the Windows LSA version :

```
# strings krb5cc_encoded_ASN1 
SOME.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN
krbtgt
SOME.EXAMPLE.DOMAIN
s*q0u
} +c
iV{P
+qwF
........
```

I don't see "myuser" in the ticket gotten from the cache.

I am using this code to get the cache from LSA.

```
try {           
    LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("SignedOnUserLoginContext");
    lc.login();
    Subject signedOnUserSubject = lc.getSubject();
    Set<Object> privateCred = signedOnUserSubject.getPrivateCredentials();

        for (Object privates : privateCred) {
            if (privates instanceof KerberosTicket) {
                KerberosTicket ticket = (KerberosTicket)privates;
                return ticket.getEncoded();
            }
        }

}
```

Can anyone advise?

thanks

Comment: Search my answers, I have done that already.

Comment: hi Michael-O, thanks. i searched but found only for 2000/2003. Does newer windows like 2012 R2 and windows 8 have this requirement to set this key? thanks

Comment: You can apply the WinXP fix to Windows 8 too.

Comment: hi Michael-O is this registry key to be created on clients as well as at the KDC/Active directory ?